# MPAndroidChart how to set x-axis to the bottom of the chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have downloaded the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library to draw a LineChart, i have noticed that this LineChart always draw the xAxis on top of yAxis, me i need to draw xAxis on bottom of yAxis

this is how i initialize the chart

```
  mChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);

    mChart.setDescription("");
    mChart.setNoDataTextDescription("You need to provide data for the chart.");

    // enable value highlighting
    mChart.setHighlightEnabled(true);

    // enable touch gestures
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);

    mChart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.9f);

    // enable scaling and dragging
    mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    mChart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(true);
    mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();

    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);




    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();

    leftAxis.setTextColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    leftAxis.setAxisMaxValue(200f);
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);


    YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    rightAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

    MyMarkerView mv = new MyMarkerView(this, R.layout.custom_marker_view);

    // set the marker to the chart
    mChart.setMarkerView(mv);
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this: `xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM)`

More that in the [documentation](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/xaxis/).

Comment: Hi Phillip, what can i do to have space between the xAxis position and the line above it?